# How to reshape data according to years in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV data that looks like this:

[image: Before reshaping]

In pandas using python, I want to convert it into something like this:

[image: After reshaping]

The point is to have the same column variables for each year, where year is the index.

I have tried out many different forms of converting the `dataframe` at hand such as pivot table, melt, stack/unstack etc. but to no avail. Any help in this regard will be appreciated!

Comment: What is `df.info()` ?

Comment: Where exactly ?

Comment: If solution work, it is not necessary. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need:

```
df = df.stack(0)
```

Sample:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2003,2004], ['C', 'D']])
mux1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2], ['A', 'B']], names=('State1','State2'))

np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,4)), columns=mux, index = mux1)
print (df)
                   2003                2004          
                      C         D         C         D
State1 State2                                        
1      A       0.543405  0.278369  0.424518  0.844776
       B       0.004719  0.121569  0.670749  0.825853
2      A       0.136707  0.575093  0.891322  0.209202
       B       0.185328  0.108377  0.219697  0.978624

print (df.stack(0).swaplevel(1,2).reset_index())
   State1  level_1 State2         C         D
0       1     2003      A  0.543405  0.278369
1       1     2004      A  0.424518  0.844776
2       1     2003      B  0.004719  0.121569
3       1     2004      B  0.670749  0.825853
4       2     2003      A  0.136707  0.575093
5       2     2004      A  0.891322  0.209202
6       2     2003      B  0.185328  0.108377
7       2     2004      B  0.219697  0.978624
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's very helpful